# Como fazer um loop dentro de uma query?

Tags: php, loop

Eu tenho uma lista de números de telefones e suas operadoras. Esta lista se apresenta em formato de ícones e quando se passa o mouse em cima aparece o número relacionado a operadora em formato de **tooltip**.
Porém está aparecendo um mesmo número para todas as operadoras como pode ser visto [aqui](http://valsegs.we-broker.com.br/), basta passar o mouse sobre o ícone do telefone no canto direito inferior.

Minha `query` está assim:

```
$tel_query = "SELECT * FROM tels";
$variavel_exe = mysql_query($tel_query) or die(mysql_error());
while($variavel = mysql_fetch_array($variavel_exe)){
    $indTelefone=0;
    $indCelular=0;
    while($tipo = mysql_fetch_array($variavel_exe)){
        if($tipo['tipo']=='fixo'){
            $arrayTelefone[$indTelefone]['numero'] = $tipo['numero'];
            $indTelefone++;
        }else{
            $arrayCelular[$indCelular]['numero'] = $tipo['numero'];
            $indCelular++;
        }
    }
}
```

Algum colega pode, por favor, me ajudar a resolver esse lance?
Obrigado!

> Em tempo, estou usando Google Material Design para a interface (o framework é fantástico) e claro, PHP com MySQL.

Comment: Percebi que tem 2 loops, 1 dentro do outro, o que exatamente você esta tentando fazer? O código está bem bagunçado, pode explicar como esta a estrutura da tabela e um exemplo em texto mesmo de como quer que fique?

Answer (score 1):

Se remover um dos laços consiguerá o resultado esperado:

```
$tel_query = "SELECT * FROM tels";
$variavel_exe = mysql_query($tel_query) or die(mysql_error());

$indTelefone=0;
$indCelular=0;
    while($tipo = mysql_fetch_array($variavel_exe)){
        if($tipo['tipo']=='fixo'){
            $arrayTelefone[$indTelefone]['numero'] = $tipo['numero'];
            $indTelefone++;
        }else{
            $arrayCelular[$indCelular]['numero'] = $tipo['numero'];
            $indCelular++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Opa, obrigado! Vou testar e ver como fica.